# Dent detection in car body

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, computer-vision

[image: Original Image]

[image: Output Image]

I have to detects dent in image  and classify them (big ones in yellow and small ones in red) and have to count number of dents in image.

By which image processing steps i can achieve this. ??(I converted to binary image  B&W lines. )

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Compare the image to a Gaussian-blurred one, to extract the stripes.

Then use contour following to get curves and detect the regions of high curvature.

[image]

Comment: I would like to know how can we follow single line separately and how to find high region of curvature..?